# Point addition in NaCl/libsodium (Curve25519)

Tags: libsodium, elliptic-curves

In NaCl and libsodium, the `crypto_scalarmult` function implements the operation $Q = kP$ (scalar/point multiplication). There doesn't seem to be a function for point addition $K = P + Q$ though.

Something like point addition must be implemented somewhere I think, as part of the implementation of scalar multiplication. It would be useful to be able to access this for developing some protocols on top of Curve25519.

- Is it deliberate that point addition isn't mentioned anywhere in the API or documentation? (Don't the authors want people implementing research-level protocols using their library?)
- `crypto_scalarmult` delegates to `crypto_scalarmult_curve25519` declared (in libsodium) in `crypto_scalarmult_curve25519.h` but I can't seem to find the definition in a `.c` file anywhere (in the latest version on GitHub)?
- Is there a safe way to implement, or reuse an internal implementation, of point addition in libsodium?

Comment: NaCl isn't an ECC library, it only offers higher level operations like key-exchange and signatures and doesn't have point addition in its public API. You should be able to find an edwards form point addition function in its Ed25519 implementation.

Comment: This is on purpose. The philosophy behind NaCl is that allowing low-level access leads to many implementation errors. If you only allow people "encrypt" and "decrypt" and you make this CCA-secure, then it's hard to mess things up. However, this does mean that you can't use the library for anything else...

Comment: You make a good point - perhaps I need to look for a different library. I was hoping for something to code a small ElGamal-based voting scheme based on ECC.

Comment: You can try OpenSSL

Comment: I like the Git concept of Plumbing and Porcelain API, say one easy and safe to use API, and another one for experts, enabling anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it deliberate that point addition isn't mentioned anywhere in the API or documentation?

Yes. The idea is to offer a minimal API that makes doing the right thing for security easy, while avoiding low level operations that allow shooting yourself in the foot.

To quote [this primer](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/securing-communication.pdf) (pdf) on NaCl:

> A typical cryptographic library is a
>   collection of many different functions
>   and supports a plethora of parameter
>   sets. It is left to the software developer
>   to choose from these functions and
>   parameters, and combine them in a way
>   that offers the desired security. These
>   choices come with various pitfalls, not
>   only because most libraries still contain
>   highly insecure functions for ‘historical’
>   or ‘compatibility’ reasons, but also
>   because it is easy to combine secure
>   functions in an insecure way
>
> The Eindhoven researchers have
>   found that this level of complication is
>   unnecessary for most applications. NaCl
>   offers an easy-to-use high-level interface
>   for exactly what applications need:
>   secure authenticated encryption.

---

> Is there a safe way to implement, or reuse an internal implementation, of point addition in libsodium?

You shouldn't even try to reuse the internal implementation by calling it from outside, because it's not a public interface. You can, of course, copy parts of [the implementation](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/tree/master/src/libsodium/crypto_scalarmult/curve25519/ref10) (it's under the ISC license) and modify it to use in your own software, but then you are on your own with respect to using it safely.

Comment: It's public domain if you copy it out of NaCl or SUPERCOP.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, true, though ISC license lets you do anything with it in any case.

Comment: After a bit more research, there's another reason why Curve25519 doesn't do point addition - the implementation only stores the $x$-coordinates of points (not even a sign bit for $y$), which is sufficient for Diffie-Hellman but not for addition. It might be to avoid patent issues, or it might just be because that's sufficient for the intended applications.

Long story short: using the Ed25519 implementation in NaCl instead does exactly what I was looking for and gives the same security guarantees.

Comment: @Bristol, you could post that as another answer if you like, or edit it into this one.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of libsodium have `crypto_core_ed25519_add()` and more: https://download.libsodium.org/doc/advanced/point-arithmetic

Comment: This only works for Ed25519 though right? You'd have to start with Ed, add the points then birationally map them to curve25519?

Comment: If you need more than scalar multiplication, just do everything over Edwards25519.

Comment: thanks you're a legend.